# A library that wraps iOS animations the same way three20 wraps UI Classes

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, uikit, uianimation

I found that [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) does a great job in simplifying grunt work when it comes to arranging and laying out buttons and views etc (amongst other things). I was wondering if there was something similar to that but for Animations instead. I have been spending a ton of time doing very basic animations that I'm sure are very common so as to merit some library or wrapper etc.

And yeah I don't want something like [cocoa controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/), that is pretty finished products.

let's say i want to slide a view to the top part of the screen and have it bounce when it hits the edge.. or like i have a list of 3 UIViews.. i want to add one after the second.. the last one slides down and makes room for the view i'm inserting.. common patterns like these nothing too fancy.. these often come custom made in many of the cocoacontrol projects.. but they have like 100 different implementations.. none of the implementations are made as an API or a library.. and so everyone winds up reinventing the wheel.. i thought a library would make sense.

Comment: Very basic animations... like?

Comment: @Alladinian updated my question with examples

Comment: Is there a specific programming question, or are you just bemoaning not having a library for something that you want to do?

Comment: @Abizern if you take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17047082/766570) below.. you'll probably understand what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Three20 UI classes - I find that, most of the time, I can start from some open-source project close enough from the result I'm looking for, but I have to play with code to become familiar with it, erase code that I don't use - in the end, there is no such thing as a golden hammer.

Still, for advanced animations, I found these [easing functions (AHEasing)](https://github.com/warrenm/AHEasing) quite useful

Comment: very nice! definitely one of the things i was looking for. Probably there isn't such a thing as a golden hammer, but a whole class of animations that i'm looking for are covered by your suggested library.. thanks!